# Can't seem to add two numbers in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have been googling and trying different methods but nothing seems to work.

I have the following code

```
string=0 4 5 27 8 7 0 6

total=0

for n in "$string"; do
 total=$(($total + $n))
done
```

This way I want to count the total sum of all the numbers within that string.

I have also tried `expr "$total" + "$n"` but that gives me an error saying the operand is not an integer.

Any suggestion how I might make this work?

Comment: Try adding `echo "-> $n"` on the first line in the `for` loop to see what goes wrong ;-) Also, are you sure you don't get an error on that first line?

Comment: echo $n lists all the numbers. Why would I get an error message on the first line?

Comment: So is that what you want? Because `$total + 0 4 5 27 8 7 0 6` doesn't seem like something you want to do?

Comment: In general, don't try to use space-separated strings as lists. `string=(0 4 5 27)` and `for n in "${string[@]}"; do` works as well, and generalizes to lists of elements that themselves contain whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't quote the string in the `in` clause, quoted string is not split into words:

```
#! /bin/bash
total=0
string='0 4 5 27 8 7 0 6'
for n in $string ; do
    (( total += n ))
done
echo $total
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string=0 4 5 27 8 7 0 6
```

This attempts to set the variable `string` to `0`, then invoke the command `4` with arguments `5 27 8 7 0 6`.

You need to quote the value:

```
string="0 4 5 27 8 7 0 6"
```

And you need to remove the quotes when you refer to it; change

```
for n in "$string"; do
```

to

```
for n in $string; do
```

Comment: Tried, made no difference. I am storing the numbers in the string by running "$(du -a "$var" | cut -f1)" if that could be somehow important.

Comment: Yep thank you, choroba above said the same thing. The quotes on the string were the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You should use :

```
total=$(( total + n ))
```

no need for the `$` before variables inside a `$(( ))` statement

Comment: True, but they're harmless. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Keith true, to be honest I've only read the title and the given code, where the addition take place.. I didn't though the question wasn't exactly as the title say! I'll be more careful next time, thanks

Comment: @bew78 Rule one of support: Never trust anything that the person asking for support claims as they can't be trusted on matters pertaining to their problem. If they fully grasped the situation, they wouldn't be asking for help ;-) Always verify and look at the context. ;-)

Comment: @KeithThompson:  they are harmless *in this case*, but they are expanded before the calculation.  Compare the results from: `echo $(( n = n + 1, x = n + 1 ))` with `echo $(( n = $n + 1, x = $n + 1 ))`